# Regex multiple detection of same matching group

Tags: regex, regex-group

i am having trouble with regex for dectecting all characters between the keyword "QUESTION"

I want to select all Question but i couldn't select a Question already present in the first match
when i use this regex (the result is bold):

```
(Question |QUESTION |QCM )(.)*?(Question |QUESTION |QCM )
```

> 

**QUESTION N°%6 : A PROPOS DE LA MYOLOGIE DE L EXTREMITE
CEPHALIQUE :
C. Le nerf facial se termine dans la loge submandibulaire. |
D. Tous les muscles peauciers sont innerves par le nerf facial. . risa baile
E. La contraction du muscle platysma entraine un abaissement de la lévre inférieure.
QUESTION** N°7 : A PROPOS DE LA MYOLOGIE DE L'EXTREMITE
CEPHALIQUE : Re ear al 30
A. Le muscle buccinateur est innervé par le nerf mandibulaire. | oe ee
B. La contraction du muscle élévateur nasolabial entraine une constriction de la narine.
**QUESTION N°8 : A PROPOS DE L'ARTICULATION TEMPOROMANDIBULAIRE :
A. Les articulations temporo-mandibulaires sont de type sphéroide.
mandibulaire.
Question**

> 

i need to match with all Questions. thank you

Comment: What's the idea around the logic for not matching the *non bolded* portion of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern with an assertion and the capture group around the whole matching part.

```
 \b(Question|QUESTION|QCM)\s+(.*?)(?=\s+(?:Question|QUESTION|QCM)\s|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(Question|QUESTION|QCM)` Capture any of the alternatives in group 1
- `\s+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(.*?)` Capture any character in group 2, as few as possible
- `(?=\s+(?:Question|QUESTION|QCM)\s|$)` Assert that to the right is either a new variation of question between whitespace chars, or the the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RTc0Tv/1)